# get value of textarea html in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, keypress

I have a textarea

```
<textarea id='inputText' rows='30' style="width: 45%; margin-left: 20%;">
```

and in Javascript when I press a key a send the value of the textare

```
 $('#inputText').keypress(function (e){
conn.send($('#inputText').val());
}
```

my problem is that when I press a key it sends the previous state of the textare. Is there a way where I can "refresh" the textarea value before sending it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$('#inputText').keyup();` since you want to run it when the key is released.

Comment: Be sure to click the check next to this answer to accept it and close this question.